# comparar datos guardados en Firebase de android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo la estructura correspondiente a los datos duardados en Firebase Database mediante android 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deseo obtener los datos señalados en rojo las ultimas 2 o 3 "dosis" guardadas.

tengo esta estructura pero no se si sea la correcta para obtener los datos y compararlos cual ha sido el mayor mediante if(){} y mostrar el resultado en pantalla.

```
my.child("usuario").orderByKey().limitToLast(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        usuario us =snapshot.getValue(usuario.class);
                        //textViewcalculo.setText(us.getDosis());
                        Log.e("Datos: " , "" + us.getDosis());
                    }

                }
```

el frangmento de codigo extrae la informacion pero no se como identificarla y obtenerla para comparar

el el debug muestra los tres ultimos, pero no me sirve asi para compararlos alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?? 
gracias

Comment: Te respondi en la otra pregunta, trata de no hacer la misma pregunta dos veces por que puede que te cierren la pregunta y te penalicen, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

sería de la siguiente manera.

```
my.child("usuario").orderByKey().limitToLast(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Usuario usuario;
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Usuario us=snapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                    if(usuario==null || usuario.getDosis()< us.getDosis()){
                       usuario = us;
                    }
                }
                Log.e("La mayor dosis es esta: " + usuario.getDosis());
            }
```

Saludos.